# How can I use DragSource and Connect for a same component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dnd

I have a react component. I want to use DragSource and Connect in the component.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(ExpandableCard);
export default DragSource(Types.CARD, cardSource, collect)(ExpandableCard);
```

How can I accomodate both the lines for a single component i.e. ExpandableCard

Answer (score 2):

[Connect](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) "returns a new, connected component class, for you to use", so `export default DragSource(Types.CARD, cardSource, collect)(connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(ExpandableCard));` should do the trick?

Comment: What if I have to add this also  export default DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)(ExpandableCard);

Comment: Then you should export these things separately and import accordingly.